# Computing the rank of $\mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am following the chapter on Morse Theory of Ambrosetti and Malchiodi's *Nonlinear Analysis and Semilinear Elliptic Problems*, and they define the rank of an abelian group as follows:

*Definition.* The rank of an abelian group $G$ is the maximal number $k$ for which $\sum_1^k n_i g_i = 0$ with $(n_i)_i \subset \mathbb Z$ and $(g_i)_i \subset G$ implies $g_i = 0$ for every $i$.

The book then gives the example that if $G = Z^p \oplus Z_q$ for some integers $p$ and $q$, then rank $G = p$.

Regarding the example, I am assuming that they mean $\mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_q$ with $p < q$ primes.

My doubt is that I am failing to see why the assertion is true. If we consider $\mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_5$, isn't
$$
(1, 0) + (2, 3) + (0, 2)= (0, 0)
$$
a counterexample? In general, wouldn't $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ generate this group?

I am sure I am missing some elementary detail, but nonetheless I will appreciate some help with this because I am truly confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rank of $\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_q$ in this sense is $0$. Note that the $p$ in their example is a superscript: $\Bbb{Z}^p \times \Bbb{Z}_q$ means the cartesian product of $p$ copies of the integers and a cyclic group of order $q$. Finite factors don't contribute to the rank.

Comment: @RobArthan I am able to justify your first claim as follows: if we let $g = (x_i, y_i) \in Z_p \times Z_q$, then $n = pq$ gives $ng = 0$. However, isn't it an inconsistency with the definition of rank as the minimal cardinality of a generating set?

Comment: Moreover, let $G = Z \times Z \times Z_q$. Isn't $(1, 1, x) - (1, 1, x) = 0$ a counterexample? I apologize for saying dumb things

Comment: The rank here is the maximum cardinality of a linearly independent set. The definition should probably say more explicitly that the $g_i$ are distinct.

Comment: It is clear now, thank you!

Comment: Good. I"ve written up an answer which I hope will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to clarify the definition. Let's say a set $g_1, \ldots g_k$ of elements of $G$ is *linearly independent* if the equation:
$$
n_1 g_1 + n_2 g_2 + \ldots + n_k g_k = 0
$$
where each $n_i \in \Bbb{Z}$ only holds if each $n_i = 0$. Note that if $g_1, \ldots, g_k$ are linearly independent, then the $g_i$ are necessarily distinct, since if $g_i = g_j$ for $i \neq j$, you have $g_i + (-1)g_j = 0$, contradicting linear independence. The rank is the maximum size of a linearly independent set. This can be seen to be well-defined and finite using the [structure theorem for finitely-generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group), which implies that any finely-generated abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to a direct sum $\Bbb{Z}^m \oplus H$, where $H$ is finite and $m$ (the rank) is uniquely determined by $G$.